# Does Mac Pro 5,1 support USB 3?

Tags: usb, mac-pro

I have a Mac Pro 5,1 running 10.7.5.

Do any of the USB ports support USB 3? Or do I need to buy a card?

Comment: By support do you mean the software will work with a specific PCI card or that the hardware is included with the Machine as shipped by Apple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No the first Mac Pro with a USB 3 port is the latest (6.1, late 2013)

From the [specifications](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP652) for your particular Mac Pro:

> Connections and audio
>
> - Four FireWire 800 ports (two on front panel, two on back panel)
> - **Five USB 2.0 ports (two on front panel, three on back panel)**
> - **Two USB 2.0 ports on included keyboard**
> - Front-panel headphone minijack and internal speaker
> - Optical digital audio input and output TOSLINK ports
> - Analog stereo line-level input and output minijacks
> - Multichannel audio through Mini DisplayPort

A quick Google search shows several PCI Express USB 3.0 cards, e.g.,

- [Sonnet Allegro USB 3.0 PCIe](http://www.sonnettech.com/product/allegrousb3pcie.html)
- [CalDigit SuperSpeed PCI Express Card](http://www.caldigit.com/avdrive/card_pciex.html)
- [HighPoint RocketU card](http://www.macworld.com/article/1165672/add_usb_3_0_to_a_mac_pro_with_highpoints_rocketu.html)

Comment: All product links dead @2023

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late, but the Inateck cards using the FL1100 chipset from FRESCO work great because that's the same chipset used in later Mac Pros. Here is a guide to installing these cards

[How to add USB 3 to a Mac Pro for under 25 quid](http://endlessgeek.com/2014/04/add-usb-3-to-a-mac-pro/)

Comment: Link dead, direct Inatek link - https://www.inateck.com/collections/pcie-card/products/pcie-to-usb-3-2-gen-2-card-with-20-gbps-bandwidth-3-usb-type-a-and-2-usb-type-c-ports-ku5211-red [This is their PCIe2 card that will work on the old cheesegraters.] 3x USB 3.2, 2x USB-C